# Render template with renderer list

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, frontend

Magento 2 renderers cart items using renderer list

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.form" as="cart-items" template="cart/form.phtml" after="cart.summary">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
```

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="cart/item/mobile.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="cart/item/mobile.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions" as="actions">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

So i want to keep the form.phtml to render things, but i also want to use another template, (for example form2.phtml) and use same renderers.

So i tried to do this (here i changed form.phtml to mobile.phtml):

```
<container name="checkout.cart.mobile.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="checkout-cart__container_mobile" before="checkout.root">
    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.mobile" as="checkout-cart-mobile" template="cart/mobile.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
    </block>
</container>
```

Now magento yells at me with this:

> Renderer list for block "checkout.cart.mobile" is not defined

So, how to define a renderer list for this block? How to make it work anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i guess i managed to move a bit further so far.

I extended the **Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml**, gave the block different name and it worked and used it with that new name.

In **Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml**:

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.mobile">
...
</referenceBlocK>
```

And then declare the block with this new name. It should work.

Comment: Which block you gave a new name??